# why is the chatacter rigg not working?

Tags: rigging

So i'm following a cg geek tutorial on animation and I open the character in blender but none of the rigs are working instead it's all acting as one single block. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyVvi-TjHlM&t=1037s
Am i missing something here?[image]

Whenever i try moving the rig the whole thing moves instead.

Comment: maybe because its in *Object Mode*? try going into *Pose Mode*

Comment: awesome thanks so much. its working great now, newb mistakes. :P